# Selecting the last 7 days from Now() in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Thankyou for taking the time to look at my question.

I have this MYSQL query:

```
foreach( $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT wp_pixelcart_calendar.datefield AS DATE,
    IFNULL(SUM(wp_pixelcart_daily_sales.quantity),0) AS total_sales
    FROM wp_pixelcart_daily_sales RIGHT JOIN wp_pixelcart_calendar ON (DATE(wp_pixelcart_daily_sales.order_date) = wp_pixelcart_calendar.datefield)
    WHERE (wp_pixelcart_calendar.datefield BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE(order_date)) FROM wp_pixelcart_daily_sales) AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(order_date)) FROM wp_pixelcart_daily_sales))
    GROUP BY DATE"
) as $key => $row) {

echo "<br>". $row->DATE . "',". $row->total_sales . "],";

}
```

I'm having a hard time to display the last seven days from now in the query, ive been playing around with:

```
BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE(order_date)) FROM wp_pixelcart_daily_sales) AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(order_date)) FROM wp_pixelcart_daily_sales))
```

To this:

```
BETWEEN NOW() FROM wp_pixelcart_daily_sales) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) FROM wp_pixelcart_daily_sales))
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

if this is not working, returning 0 results, consider swapping the dates' range:

```
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Comment: Ive tried this but doesn't seem to produce any results  WHERE (wp_pixelcart_calendar.datefield BETWEEN NOW() and DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))

Comment: If you remove this from the WHERE clause, are there any results being returned? If so, are the dates of those results during the past 7 days?

Comment: I removed the WHERE and left the BETWEEN NOW()... and the results show up but not from the last seven days. If it helps i'm using this code from this tutorial http://www.richnetapps.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/

Comment: You may need to update the dates in the datefield column to be during the past 7 days (ex: 2011-09-03, 2011-09-04, etc) in order for them to show up in the query results.

Comment: Hey, figured it out. Thanks for the help  WHERE (wp_pixelcart_calendar.datefield BETWEEN ('2011-09-01') AND ('2011-09-20'))

Answer (score 5):

You could just write:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_field > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE order_date <= NOW() AND order_date >= DATE_SUB(order_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: Take care! This answer is INCORRECT. It should be `DATE_SUB(NOW()`