# How can I get MySQL records from past 7 days, but only days that have a record, and return each day as a record?

Tags: php, mysql

Say I've got a simple mysql table with columns id, title, date. Each day can have several rows, but not *every* day has a row. For example there might be 5 rows with June 15th as the date, but zero rows with June 14th as the date. How can I get all results from the past 7 days, excluding June 14th because it has no rows. So I'm not just subtracting 7 days from the current date. I want to get only the past 7 days which have any rows at all.

Then I want to return each day as a single result, like a group by date, but by the year/month/day part of the timestamp, so that what I get back is only 7 results, and each result is like an array of individual rows.

I hope that makes sense. Any ideas?

Edit:
I realized I can do it something like this:

`WHERE Date BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL DATEDIFF( NOW(), (SELECT Date FROM test GROUP BY Date LIMIT 7,1 ) ) DAY ) and NOW()`

But this gives an SQL syntax error. What I'm trying to do is a subquery and group by date to get one result for each day, and return one result starting at offset 7, then do a `DATEDIFF` on that to get the number of days that `DATE_SUB` should put in the `INTERVAL x DAYS`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Have you looked at other related Stack Overflow posts? [Selecting the last 7 days from Now() in MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341658/selecting-the-last-7-days-from-now-in-mysql)

Comment: @Aiias that's a step in the right direction. I don't need the last 7 days, I need only the last 7 days which actually have something, which  could actually be the last 20 days if only 7 of those 20 days have data entered. If I can figure out how many days to go back, then I could use BETWEEN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: It works!

`WHERE Date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL (DATEDIFF( NOW(), (SELECT Date FROM test GROUP BY Date ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 8,1 ) ) ) DAY) and NOW()`

I was missing a parentheses, and I had to add ORDER BY and DESC to the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to get the same day results back as an array, but you can group it by date, with the titles comma separated:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(title) AS titles, date 
FROM test 
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY date;
```

Then in PHP, do something like this:

```
foreach ($results as $row)
{
    echo $row['date'];
    foreach ($row['titles'] as $title)
    {
        echo $title;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would get literally everything from the last 7 days, which is not what I'm looking for. What I want is only the last 7 days which have anything in them. This query doesn't check if there are rows in that day or not.

Comment: @eablokker as far as I am concerned if a given day have no entries then nothing will be posted on that day and that day won't be display, so what you want is that if any of the past 7 days have no entry it will go back another day until you have 7 days of data ?

Comment: @eablocker Have you run the query? Any days with nothing in them (i.e. blank rows) will not be returned because they don't exist. EDIT - ahhh I get it now; you want 7 days worth of data, not data from the last 7 days. It wasn't clear, sorry.

Comment: Yes I want it to keep going until I get 7 days worth of data. I figured it out with a subquery.