# Finding the Last Week Report From Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have employees data base where every day a person enter the data in the time entry system.
like he will enter the

1. project details
2. Task Name
3. Hours worked for a day(Mon,Tues so on
4. Description For a particular Day(Ex:Mon)
5. Total Hours (Worked will Displayed)

I am able to fetch the details from start to till date

Now as per my new requirement i want to fetch the details only for last week

Can anybody tell me how do i fetch it using mysql and php

Comment: see post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341658/selecting-the-last-7-days-from-now-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `YOUR_TABLE_NAME`
WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

Check for more DATE related functions here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate

Comment: Now i am able to fetch the last week data and now i want to copy the data to the present week can u suggest me how i can do that..?? That is from (Mon - Fri) thank you

Comment: @Mac You want to save the data in another field?

Comment: @Mac if this is the case then you can try something like this as specified in the link and let me know the case then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526856/copy-from-one-column-to-another-different-tables-same-database-mysql

Comment: No as per ur query i am able to fetch the last week data...now i want to put the last week data in this week data . Like take an example saying that i fetch the data from last of week of mon-fri(24june-28june) those data i want to put in this week as mon-fri(1july-5july) u got my point..???

Comment: can anybody tel me how do i fetch the completed date and time of particular column...as per the above requirement i am able to fetch the last week detail but not along with time...

Comment: can anybody tel me how do i fetch the completed date and time of particular column...as per the above requirement i am able to fetch the last week detail but not along with time...

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the details only for last week, something like this:

```
$last_monday = strtotime('last monday');

select * from table where table.date<$last_monday and table.date>$last_monday-(86400*7)
```

hope will help

Comment: confused with ur query @ejaz

Comment: @Mac strtotime('last monday') will bring you the date of  last Monday from current date and after that i m trying to get 7 days before Monday so i can get full last week, like this $last_monday-(86400*7).