# Selecting the next 7 days from table

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, intervals, between

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE inpDATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW();
```

This query shows me 7 days ago, but I want to see next 7 days (including today).

---

Using @ExplosionPills answer give me this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE inpDATE BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Yes, now it works, but it doesn't show me today's posts - this query shows me `2013-11-21/22/23/24`, but excludes `2013-11-20`. How can I fix this?

Comment: I would suggest having a look at the [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function instead of DATE_SUB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting the last 7 days from Now() in MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341658/selecting-the-last-7-days-from-now-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

Change `DATE_SUB` to `DATE_ADD`.  You may also have to reverse the order of arguments to `BETWEEN`, but I'm not sure.

```
BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness since the question was amended, to include results from today you want to compare to `CURDATE()` instead of `NOW()` as well as using `DATE_ADD` as explained by @ExplosionPills.

```
WHERE inpDate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: This is the solution. Why does this work, unlike the solution based on `NOW()`? `CURDATE()` returns a `DATE` whereas `NOW()` returns a `DATETIME` (therefore including a **time** parameter). Assuming `inpDATE` is also `DATETIME`, "`inpDATE > CURDATE()`" means "`inpDATE` later than today at 00:00, while "`inpDATE > NOW()`" means "`inpDATE` later than *now* at this very moment".