# Count SQL Rows based on Date Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm building a really simple PHP app where they just want to list out their current orders (from an SQL database) and make a few calls based on when the due date of the orders are.

**I'm trying to count all the orders in the table that have due dates less than 6 days from now...** and I am STRUGGLING!

I've got it displaying all the orders in a table, but I have no idea how to approach counting the rows based on their due date.

The `order_duedate` is in date format.

Does anyone have any suggestions??

I'm pretty new to pulling info from databases so this could be quite simple - Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php

ob_start();
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'aaa');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'aaa');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'aaa');
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
$database = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());

// TABLE ROWS AS FOLLOWS
// order_no / order_client / order_duedate / order_status


$table_all = "SELECT * FROM orders";
$table_all_data = mysql_query($table_all);


// COUNT ORDERS THAT HAVE ORDER_DUEDATE < 6 DAYS FROM NOW


?>

<p>TOTAL OVERDUE ORDERS</p>
<p><?php echo $total_overdue ?></p>



<?php
// DISPLAY COMPLETE TABLE OF DATA
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table_all_data)){ 
    // CHANGE FORMAT OF DATE
    $reformat_duedate = $row['order_duedate'];
    $phpdate = strtotime( $reformat_duedate );
    $newdate = date( 'd/m/Y', $phpdate );

?>

<tr>
    <td><a href=""><?php echo $row['order_no'] ?></a></td>
    <td class="alignleft"><?php echo $row['order_client'] ?></td>
    <td><span class="date open"><?php echo $newdate ?></span></td>
    <td class="alignleft"><?php echo $row['order_status'] ?></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=""><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr>


<?php } 

mysql_close(); ?>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341658/selecting-the-last-7-days-from-now-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE date_add(order_duedate, INTERVAL -6 DAY) < now()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_duedate <= NOW() + INTERVAL 6 DAY`

Answer (score 0):

Run another query:

```
select count(*) from orders where order_duedate < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 6 DAY;
```